# How can i make overlapping menu like "Android Navigation Drawer Menu" in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, user-interface

**How can i make Overlapping menu like "Android Navigation Drawer menu" in ios(In Swift Language). Like the Pictures Below.**

*I have used SWRevealViewController but it doesn't solved my problem because it pushes the home screen not overlap on it.*

Please tell me how do i make it by my own or by using third party like SWRevealViewController or MMDrawer etc.

Note: I'm Strictly finding the solution for overlapping menu.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Slide menu could be a UIView. To present your menu you must locate the menu view outside UIViewController's view. That is

```
CGRect(x: [viewcontroller_width], y: 0, width: [menu_width], height: [menu_height])
```

At the moment present menu view to use the [insertSubview(: aboveSubview:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622570-insertsubview) from form UIViewController's view. This brings the menu view to the front over all views.

Next step it's to register two swipe gesture in your UIViewController's view to present and hide the menu.

For better visual experience you should add a shadow to your menu view.

I use this kind of menu in [one of my apps](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/meteo-just-weather-forecast/id1012286721?mt=8), if need more help write a comments ;)

Comment: How can i make menu_Width 50% or 70% of the home Screen.

Comment: 50% = CGRect(x: [viewcontroller_width], y: 0, width: [menu_width / 2], height: [menu_height])